# File upload with Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

How do I access the uploaded file in Tornado, when using a `put` request?

```
@require_basic_auth
class UploadFile(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def put(self, params):
        path = calculate_path(params)
        # TODO: create an empty binary file at path and then copy 
        # the request input stream to it.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@require_basic_auth
class UploadFile(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def put(self, params):
        path = calculate_path(params)
        with open(path, 'wb') as out:
            body = self.request.get_argument('data')
            out.write(bytes(body, 'utf8'))
```

...was what I needed.

Found on some ActiveState pages.

Comment: `bytes` only accepts one argument (python 2.7), is there a typo?

Answer (score 10):

`self.request.files` should be fine. Here is an [example](http://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/tornado-file-uploads/).